# Tiles of 2 different Promoted list getting merge in sharepoint site page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have two promoted lists one "Sample 1" having 6 tiles and other "Sample 2" with 3 tiles. One of my tasks was to show the  tiles in rows and columns  for "Sample 1" which I am able to do. But when I try to add another promoted list under "Sample 1" list after segregating in rows and columns using jquery. My "Sample 1" tiles are merging with "Sample 2". I am doing this in in SharePoint site page. Below is the result I am getting. How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: Adding the code you using for creating your own styling would be very helpful, since it is surely the source of your problem

Comment: Hi Can you help me in finding the solution from merging the tiles or is there any other way to over come from this issue

Comment: Without seeing your code / script /CSS etc. It is very difficult to help you out I'm afraid

Comment: I used the jquery code from this link https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/542523